# Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard_iPhone'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm working on an application and everything was running in the iPhone and iPad simulator. But when was testing on the iPhone I received the following message:

> Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard_iPhone'

But I can see and change the two Storyboards in Project Navigator. When I checked the Build Phases according to another question on SO, I found that there is something wrong but I don't know what to do. What is wrong?

This is the Build Phases, which I believe have a problem:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using some kind of versioning software? I tend to have the same issue when pulling a project from Git sometimes, and adding the missing files from their respective folders fix it.

Comment: @Locke +1 yeah that does have an awful tendency of happening when I'm not at all in the mood to deal with that kind of BS, and as for this question... just to make this completely clear, the red text for your storyboards simply means that the .storyboard files themselves are one way or another missing from the project.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to :

- "Show in finder on both files"
- "Save it to a safe place" >
- "Remove file from Xcode (reference)"
- "Add Files to your project" (With the 2 storyboards)